# Unit test breaks after dependencies update for Node 16

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I just made some changes to my project's package.json:

> - removed bundle-buddy-webpack-plugin
> - upgraded eslint from 4.11.0 to **6.0.0**
> - upgraded prettier from 1.14.3 to **2.0.0**
> - upgraded webpack from 4.28.1 to **4.36.0**

Besides the above, all I did was formatting some text as lint wanted. That was all the changes.

But for some reason, on Windows, some unit tests that expect value break. Before these changes I was getting a number**DOT**decimals. Now, my expect fails because it gets number**COMMA**decimals. Also I change Windows System Separator from comma to dot but it isn't helping.

[image: jest unit tests failing because it receives comma instead of dot]

Why this is a problem is that on my colleague mac it works just fine, as well on Jenkins where all suites of unit tests are running when creating a merge request.

Does anyone have any idea why this behavior occurs?

Comment: Could it be a locale difference inside of Node?

Comment: So it means what you test is not reliable and test is written to be bad. Fix whatever returns `,` and not `.` (seems like locale dependant)

Comment: You can try to run `new Intl.NumberFormat().resolvedOptions().locale` inside both of your Node-REPL to see if the default locales are different

Comment: Yes they are. On Mac it has locale 'en-US' and on Windows it is 'ro-RO'. So it seems for US the decimal separator is comma and for RO dot. This doesn't affect how the component works, only what's displayed to the user. But how can verify this in a reliable manner? Once the snapshot is updated to comma, it will break for the other OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue/difference. It was indeed the locale. It seems that it took that locale and used that format. Is interesting that before the upgrade above, I was calling toLocaleString with undefined and it used the EN format, but now it uses the system's one.

**The solution** was to change my system's Region/Format to whatever I was expecting to receive.

Comment: Thank you for participate, something to read and smile for you! :D

Cheers
-J

https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.13768884.2097962762.1643640040-714562313.1643640040